# c# clear textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have this code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add pgs selected to array, array needs to be global? combobox1 accCollection.Items.Add(value);
        textbox18.text = "";
        pgHolder[pgCount] = comboBox1.Text + ", "; // error here why?
        pgCount++;

        foreach(string Pg in pgHolder)
        {
            pgTemp = Pg;
            pgHolder1 += pgTemp;
        }

        textBox18.Text = pgHolder1;
    }
```

I've attempted a `txtbox.text = "";` but this doesn't work. Am I missing something here? Is there a `.clear` or do I need to do something fancy?

As you can tell I'm trying to clear the text box each time I click the button.

!!UPDATE!!
my string array is declared with default values of "0,0,0,0"
ok it looks like it wasnt the textbox but my logic, heres what happens

Clicked,  combo box = "50",  displays "50,0,0,0"
Clicked,  combo box = 75 ,   displays "50,0,0,0,50,75,0,0"

i need it to display 50,75,0,0.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" and be specific about the error.

Comment: What are you developing? ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF? What is pgHolder? And how are you clearing the textbox? You set textBox18.Text to another variable, not to "" or string.Empty

Comment: c#, winforms.. pgholder is a string array.

Comment: I think you need to clear pgTemp and pgHolder1 before your foreeach. Try pgHolder = stringEmpty; pgTemp = string.Empty;

Comment: yehah ive added pgholder1 = string.empty before the foreach loop, works perfect now!  thanks for the help!

Comment: Offtopic i don't think you will know what is `textBox18` a week later, try using some relevant names

Comment: yeh ill be changing the names after this method is complete, i was auto generating the controls using the forms interface gui.  i Should change each one when i create, but i was rushing through to test something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pgHolder` is an array of string types then you can use `string.Empty`.
Also you need to make sure that `pgCount` is an index value that is within the array.

Also when settinig UI text box values you may need to `Invoke` the change after checking `InvokeRequired`. This shouldn't be a required if the setting is performed in a WinForm code behind.

Comment: that part is fine.  i do not wish to clear the array im adding whatever is in the combo box each click.  its simply to display each time i click.  so i need to clear each time else it will look like this "combo = 50"  output = 50,0,0,0....then i click again combo = 75 out put = 50,0,0,0,50,75,0,0....i need it to clear the textbox

Comment: i have a feeling its my count

Comment: nope my count is fine, its when i add the temp to the main string, its cycling through all of the pgs, which by defualt is 4 zero values, so it will add 4 everytime.

Comment: needed pgholder = string.empty for it to work  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to empty the textbox-

1) you can do it by textbox18.text = ""

```
         OR
```

2) do it by textbox18.Clear()

Comment: You are not maintaining the array i.e pgHolder[]. The code is written in a button click event and how come you are changing the combobox value.Eventhough if you had changed the combobox value and clicked on a button then do you persist the previous value in the array. And hence no efect of the clear method here.

Comment: it was the string not being emptyed before i re-enter the loop